# How add attachment into embedded message using EWS

Tags: exchange-server, attachment, exchangewebservices

I have a message with ebbedded message, that has own attachment. I have to send this to server using EWS. I can send message with embedded message as attachment, but can't send its attachment, besause AttachmentType doesn't allow add attachment to attachment. Do you know any other ways to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround in that situation that should work is to use the MIMEContent of the ItemAttachment eg

`itemAttachment.Load(newPropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent));`

and then either create a Message based on that or add that as an attachment on a new message eg

```
        FolderId  folderid= new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,"MailboxName");    
        Folder Inbox = Folder.Bind(service,folderid);  
        ItemView ivItemView =  new ItemView(1) ;     
        FindItemsResults<Item> fiItems = service.FindItems(Inbox.Id,ivItemView);
        if(fiItems.Items.Count == 1){  
        EmailMessage mail = new EmailMessage(service);   
        EmailMessage OriginalEmail = (EmailMessage)fiItems.Items[0];
        PropertySet  psPropset= new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);    
        psPropset.Add(ItemSchema.MimeContent);
        psPropset.Add(ItemSchema.Subject);
        OriginalEmail.Load(psPropset);  
        ItemAttachment Attachment = mail.Attachments.AddItemAttachment<EmailMessage>();
        Attachment.Item.MimeContent = OriginalEmail.MimeContent;  
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_Flags = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3591, MapiPropertyType.Integer);    
        Attachment.Item.SetExtendedProperty(PR_Flags,"1");    
        Attachment.Name = OriginalEmail.Subject;  
        mail.Subject = "See the Attached Email";  
        mail.ToRecipients.Add("glen.scales@domain.com");
        mail.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Cheers
Glen